# Remove required redirect from Observer Model?

Tags: checkout, magento-1, quote

The following module does what I intended, direct a visitor to the cart with a quote id from the sales_flat_quote table specified using the "quote" GET variable, and it will restore the contents of that cart.

The only way I could get this to work was to add a redirect at the end, a redirect in a "Model" class seems like the wrong approach (this is my first foray into Magento programming). Is there a better way to approach this?

```
class XXX_RestoreCart_Model_Observer
{
    public function restoreCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        if (!$quoteId = $request->getParam('quote'))
            return false;

        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                 ->load($quoteId);
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)
                ->setReservedOrderId(NULL)
                ->save();

            $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
            $session->replaceQuote($quote);

            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getURL('checkout/cart'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer is quite a specific model.

And there's nothing wrong with using redirects there. Lots of companies including us) use this technique in their extensions, and it works absolutely fine.